# Page not found error

Tags: templating, routing

After setting up a template file `article.html` in `craft/templates` folder, and creating the `section article` with the `uri article` and setting the entry template as `article` in the admin, on trying to see the Live Preview of the page when I go to it in the entries list I get a Craft page with the error:

> Page not found

I thought it might have something with cache maybe, so I cleared that, but I still got the same error. Why I am getting this error, and how can I fix that?

Answer (score 2):

I restored the database backup that came with your ticket locally and created an `article.html` template in `craft/templates` and was able to load the route on the front-end of the site as well as get it to display in Live Preview.

My guess is that either 1) there's something wacky with the permissions on that file that Craft/PHP can't read it or 2) there's a `.htaccess` rewrite rule in your setup that's interfering with that request.